# Remove empty Html tag from RTE

Tags: richtext-editor

Is it possible to remove empty html Tags like

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

from RTE, because they are getting inserted very easy and destroying the design.

The best would be automaticaly :-) on save or publish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `item:saving` event. Be aware that in some cases saving of the item can be intercepted so not necessarily your changes will be saved.

```
<sitecore>
  <events>
    <event name="item:saving">
      <handler type="My.Assembly.Namespace.RemoveEmptyParagraphsFromRichTextProcessor,
        My.Assembly" method="OnItemSaving" />
    </event>
  </events>
</sitecore>
```

and the code

```
public class RemoveEmptyParagraphsFromRichTextProcessor
{
    protected void OnItemSaving(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Item newItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

        if (newItem == null || newItem.Database.Name != "master")
        {
            return;
        }

        Item originalItem = newItem.Database.GetItem(newItem.ID, newItem.Language, newItem.Version);

        var differences = FindDifferences(newItem, originalItem);

        foreach (var fieldName in differences)
        {
            var value = newItem[fieldName];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                newItem[fieldName] = RemoveParagraphWithSpace(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<string> FindDifferences(Item newItem, Item originalItem)
    {
        newItem.Fields.ReadAll();

        return newItem
            .Fields
            .Where(x => x.Type.Equals("Rich Text"))
            .Select(f => f.Name)
            .Where(fieldName => newItem[fieldName] != originalItem[fieldName])
            .ToList();
    }

    private string RemoveParagraphWithSpace(string html)
    {
        // you can be more creative here
        return html.Replace("<p>&nbsp;</p>", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Only thing I would suggest is to consider using HtmlAgilityPack instead of a string replace.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain that's why I used "you can be more creative here" comment. Question was only about removing `p` tag with space in it. If that's the only requirement then `string.replace` is much faster. If more complex processing of html is needed, `HtmlAgilityPack` is the good way. You're right.